# Fade out object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

How i can fade out one object immediately after colliding with it?

I cant use `Destroy (gameObject);`because that object is a coin game with efx sound, if I destroy this once the object sound does not play when the player collides with the coin.

And if I do not destroy that, coin immediately, you earn points every time you bump this coin

I'm using Audio Mixer, so really need the sound of the coin comes from the Audio Source to can set the volume on my settings.

My idea:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
{
    if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "Bee") {

        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play();

        // Here set Fade ou immediateley (idk how do)

        // Set Box Collider FALSE, no more extra points =]
        this.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;

        score.AddScore (point);

        // Destroy object after 1 sec, now can play efx sound
        Destroy (gameObject, 1f);
    }

    if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "floor") {
        Destroy (gameObject, 1.5f);

}
```

Current CODE:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
{
    if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "Bee") {

        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play();
        score.AddScore (point);
        Destroy (gameObject);
    }

    if (colisor.gameObject.tag == "floor") {
        Destroy (gameObject, 1.5f);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to fade anything. Just attach the AudioSource to the Bee GameObject that does not get destroyed then get reference to it in the Start function. Also use `gameObject.CompareTag` instead `if gameObject.tag`

```
AudioSource coinCollectSound;

void Start()
{
    coinCollectSound = GameObject.Find("Bee").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
    {
        if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag ("Bee"))
        {

            coinCollectSound.Play();

            score.AddScore (point);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag("floor"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject, 1.5f);

        }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Not mentioned in your question that you have 3 sounds.

Create GameObjects named **COINSOUNDS** then create **3** extra GameObjects under it. Rename them to `COINSOUND1`,`COINSOUND2`,`COINSOUND3` and attach `AudioSource` to **each** of them. Don't attach `AudioSource` to the COINSOUNDS(parent GameOBject).

`COINSOUND1`,`COINSOUND2`,`COINSOUND3` must be child of **COINSOUNDS** GameObject.

```
AudioSource[] coinCollectSound;

void Start()
{    
    coinCollectSound = new AudioSource[3];
    coinCollectSound[0] = GameObject.Find("COINSOUNDS/COINSOUND1").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    coinCollectSound[1] = GameObject.Find("COINSOUNDS/COINSOUND2").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    coinCollectSound[2] = GameObject.Find("COINSOUNDS/COINSOUND3").GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}


void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
{
    if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag("Bee"))
    {

        coinCollectSound[0].Play();//Play COINSOUND1
        coinCollectSound[1].Play();//Play COINSOUND2
        coinCollectSound[2].Play();//Play COINSOUND3

        score.AddScore (point);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag("floor"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject, 1.5f);

    }
}
```

**SOLUTION 3**

You can also use `coroutine`. Start coroutine, fade the image, play sound, wait for sound to finish playing, then destroy. This can only be done in coroutine. This looks better than my other solution.You don't have to modify anything in your current scene with the code below.

```
SpriteRenderer coinSpriteRenderer;
AudioSource coinCollectSound;

void Start()
{
    coinCollectSound = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    coinSpriteRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D colisor)
{
    if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag("Bee"))
    {

        score.AddScore (point);
        StartCoroutine(fadeAndWaitForSound(1));
    }

    if (colisor.gameObject.CompareTag("floor"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(fadeAndWaitForSound(1));
    }

}

IEnumerator fadeAndWaitForSound(float fadeTimeInSeconds = 1)
{

    Color currentColor = coinSpriteRenderer.color;

    Color invisibleColor = coinSpriteRenderer.color;
    invisibleColor.a = 0; //Set Alpha to 0


    float counter = 0;

    //Play sound
    coinCollectSound.Play();

    //Wait till sound is done playing
    while (coinCollectSound.isPlaying)
    {
        yield return null; 
    }

    //Now Fade texture
    while (counter < fadeTimeInSeconds)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        coinSpriteRenderer.color = Color.Lerp(currentColor, invisibleColor, counter / fadeTimeInSeconds);
        yield return null;
    }

    //Destroy after fading
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: works fine hehe, but I have 3 different coins, as I do with the other 2?

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende Attach the-same script to your 3 different coins. It will still do the-same thing. play sound then get destroyed

Comment: I expressed badly, 3 different coins sfx sounds.

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende ok. Do you have to know which sound is which or do you just want to randomly play one of those 3 sounds?

Comment: Each sound is specific.

Comment: @AlanVieiraRezende Modified the answer. Good luck!

Comment: I made minor changes to fit what I wanted, it was perfect! Thank you again!

Comment: Woo very nice scripts, I have plenty of options! I will use them and store them, this can save me again in the future !!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this:

On collision, do immediate things like update character stats/etc

Set the object to inactive (if you need to)

Do cleanup things (play sound etc)

Destroy object

This tutorial has objects being destroyed but still playing sounds. It might be helpful : http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/audio?playlist=17147

Comment: I try Set Inactve, but i dont want that object frozen on the screen to be destroyed, i try too setKinemact False, but no way this was satisfactory.

Comment: So you want it to still be visible, just not moving? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. SetActive = false doesn't destroy it, it just disables it, you can turn it back on by doing SetActive = true